# app.js is not working Django/Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, django, django-templates, django-staticfiles

I want to add to my Django project Angularjs, but my app.js is not loading. But when i go to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/js/app.js` its there. Dont get it, what i doing wrong.

**base.html**

```
 ...
{% block content %}
{% endblock %}
       ...    

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../../assets/js/vendor/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
        <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>    
        <script src="{% static 'js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js' %}"></script>
        <script src="{% static 'js/angular.min.js' %}"></script>
        <script src="{% static 'js/angular-route.js' %}"></script>
        {% block extra_javascript %}{% endblock extra_javascript %}
```

**content-template.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% block content %}

        ...

        <div class="container" ng-app="test">
            <div ng-controller="testCtrl">
             <div class="data">
             </div>
             <button ng-click="save()">Click</button>
         </div>
        </div>
{% endblock %}
{% block extra_javascript %}
<script scr="{% static 'js/app.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock extra_javascript %}
```

**app.js**

```
    app = angular.module('test', [])
    .config(function ($interpolateProvider, $httpProvider, $resourceProvider){
         $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[').endSymbol(']]');
        $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
        $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';
        $resourceProvider.defaults.stripTrailingSlashes = false;
});

app.controller('testCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.num = 0;

    $scope.save = function(){
        $(".data").html("Click" + $scope.num);
        $scope.num +=1;
    };
}]);
```

**view-source**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6drJ.png)

Comment: Is there a 404 error? Did you try breakpoints in app.js?

Comment: @ailerifren no its not 404 error

Comment: If you open the JavaScript console in the browser, do you see an error?

Comment: @dkarchmer `Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.3/$injector/modulerr?p0=test&p1=Error%3A%20…20(http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A8000%2Fstatic%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%3A20%3A463)` `angular.min.js:39`
But its error appears, cuz of app.js is not loading

Comment: Are you sure? Because it looks like all your angular code is there so if it is not loaded, why are you getting any angular errors? To test this, just move the app.js to your base template, just to test it the error goes away and it works. I just don't see how a block statement won't work

Comment: @dkarchmer maybe because a initialize ng-app test in my template. And i solved this porblem by posting my source code from app.js to template.Thank you for your time